# git-ftp just the contents of a directory

Tags: ftp, jekyll, git-ftp

I'm trying to git-ftp just the contents of a particular directory. For clarity I will describe my exact problem in case there is another fix:

I have a Jekyll generated static site and I am trying to use git-ftp to upload it to my blog subdomain. I'm using the `--syncroot` flag to only git-ftp my `_site` directory, but it is uploading the directory itself (expected behaviour really). But now when I go to my blog url, I don't end up on the index page, I get a list of files and directories - one of which is `_site`, then when I click on that link I get through to my page.

So if I could upload just the contents of `_site` to the root of my website, that would be great, or if you have any ideas on how to fix this they would be very welcome.

Comment: `git config git-ftp.syncroot _site/` (with the "/" at the end) should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @marcanuy - but didn't work for me, although I only ran it with the `--dry-run` flag so I'm not 100% sure, but it didn't look like it was going to work.

Answer (score 1):

So I wasn't able to find a way to upload just the contents of the `_site` directory as it stands, but I did come up with a solution that suited my needs and it might help someone else if they come across this question.

What I did was ignored the `_site` directory from my project, then I moved into the `_site` directory and initialized a new git repo. So now I was tracking the directory I wanted directly, I was then able to use git-ftp to just ftp the contents of the folder, as it only uploads the contents of the directory it's initialized in. This was perfect for my needs, as there wasn't any real need to track the `_site` directory in my project anyway, seeing as it was a generated folder.

Looking forward to someone posting a better answer than this.

Answer (score 0):

How about copying the contents of `_site` to a folder outside of your git repo, e.g. a `publish` folder and then pushing its contents with git ftp using a bash script?

```bash
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S` #timestamp the commit below  
bundle exec jekyll build #update your _site directory  

cp -r _site/* ../publish/. #copy files from the _site to the publish folder  
cd ~/path/to/publish #cd into the publish folder  
git add .  
git commit -m "Deploy timestamp: $date" #add everything new and commit with a timestamp to the publish git repo 

git ftp catchup
git ftp push
```